# Dynamically determine get or post call in form_tag

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am new to ruby on rails and I have a fundamental question. I have a form which has been defined via ruby inject which looks like below,

```
<%= form_tag("/#{params['controller']}/index", :method => "get", :class => "search", :id => "fSearch" ) do %>
  <%= render 'fsearch_filter' %>
<%end %>
```

In `fsearch_filter.html.erb`, I have a text area which looks like this:

```
<%= text_area_tag 'filter[fno]', @default[:fno], rows: 10, cols: 20, class: 'formlabel' %>
```

So basically I want the form "fSearch" to use a "get" call to talk to the server, if  the text area "filter[fno]" is empty, else it should use a "post" call. Is there any way I can do this with ruby on rails ?

Comment: You can do this through Javascript

Answer (score 1):

The below solution may help you....

```
function changeMethod() {
    var text_info = $("#filter_fno").val();
    if (text_info != "")
    { 
      $("#fSearch").attr("method", "post");
    }
}
```

Call the above JavaScript method on form submission.